# website security FORCED download

Tags: .htaccess, security, web

Currently when you go on our site, it puts a forced download to users, I checked our sources by pressing f12 and I saw another unknown site on it which runs a js script to force a download.

What should I do to stop it? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've been hacked.

Cleaning up after a hack is by far not a trivial task. Many will even argue one CANNOT restore trust in a formerly hacked system, as attackers can install things like root-kits etc.

Your easiest path is:

1. Shutdown the services your current server is offering.
   You do this to prevent yourself and others (visitors e.g.) from getting infected with all sorts of nastiness.
2. Get a new server, start from a clean base.
3. Make a copy of files you need to rebuild the services, but do NOT trust them
4. Inspect and make 100% sure everything you reuse is 100% clean. Sometimes the bad parts can hide in e.g. databases, so you really need to be on a maniacal level to ensure it's 100% clean.
5. If you can: figure out how they got in, and make sure not to repeat the same mistake on the new server.
6. Rebuild your service
7. Keep your service secure. Apply patches to OS, services, make sure what's developed on top is secure, ... do reviews, ...